# Add initial and final date to Range Selector Highstock

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I've got a chart with Highstock and a Range-Selector. I can only see a few dates points in the navigator. I want to be able to display the initial date and the final one as well. How can I configure this?

I tried to check with the tick amount and some axis props but not luck found there.

```
//A,B,C data array
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [
      { data: A },
      { data: B },
      { data: C }
    ]
});
```

What I want is to be able to set a start date and an end date on the range-selector navigator.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usvonfjh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `navigator.xAxis.tickPositions` where you can pass an array with ticks to be displayed and `navigator.xAxis.labels.formatter` to make readable dates from tick positions timestamps.

**Code:**

```
  navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      tickPositions: aSerie.map(elem => elem[0]),
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.value);
        },
        align: 'center'
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rx18hL37/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis.labels.formatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat